# How to change hotspot password of ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hotspot

The default password for ubuntu hotspot is difficult to memories.What code(s) can be used in terminal to change it ? If hotspot name can also be changed then attach the code(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `nm-connection-editor`. It should work on all Debian based distros such as Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Edit the hotspot configuration file.**

```
This is done by going to the System menu and selecting: Wi-Fi Off > Turn On
Next, select Wi-Fi Settings
In the Wi-Fi Settings window, click on the Gnome menu icon from the window upper right-hand side corner, and select Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot:
```

**Option 2: NM Connection Editor.**

```
You can start it by pressing Alt + F2
And type: nm-connection-editor
```

And then restart the service
    sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

[enter link description here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-ubuntu.html)